# Image not showing (tkinter in python)

Tags: python, tkinter

When I try to insert the image into my Tkinter window all that shows up is
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxtN0.png)

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("To Do List")
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=900, width=1000, bg='white')
frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#000000")
img = tk.PhotoImage("deathnote.png")
entry = tk.Entry(frame, font='system', fg='white', bg='black')
imglabel = tk.Label(frame, image=img)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8, relx=0.1, rely=0.1)
imglabel.grid(row=0, column=2)
entry.grid(row=1, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Should be `img = tk.PhotoImage(file="deathnote.png")`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using PIL:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("To Do List")
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=900, width=1000, bg='white')
frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#000000")
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("deathnote.png"))
entry = tk.Entry(frame, font='system', fg='white', bg='black')
imglabel = tk.Label(frame, image=img)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8, relx=0.1, rely=0.1)
imglabel.grid(row=0, column=2)
entry.grid(row=1, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I was doing that previously and it says "_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "deathnote.png"

Comment: Weird. that works for me. I just updated my answer. Look up and try it

Comment: If it matters I'm using Pycharm to do this. when I try to import PIL it doesn't recognize it and when I try to install it the error message is "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PIL"

Comment: Do not install "PIL". You have to install Pillow: `pip3 install Pillow` if you are using python 3 or `pip install Pillow` if you are using python 2